# How to create a vector pattern with arbitrary sized/rotated objects?

Tags: vector, inkscape, patterns, texture

I want to achieve the effect below in inkscape:

[image]

I tried with **extensions > generate from path > clone along path**, and **edit > clone > create tiled clones** with various randomized values, but nothing gives me the desired effect.

So how do I create a pattern with objects that have a random size and rotation in inkscape? or is this effect created by any other software like Illustrator etc.?

Comment: How to fill the shape with random size shape

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use [this script](http://mai-tools.com/random-pattern-light) for random element distribution. It can place your elements with random angle and size (with max and min size adjustments). Then you can cut unnecessary elements by your path and do the final tuning manually add or delete a few elements.

Comment: This question is tagged for Inkscape, not Illustrator.